# Flex wrap issue in TailwindCSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

This is what I have:

```
"Hey there" <image> "more text"
```

However, it's wrapping after the image, even though it should be able to fit a few "whats up"'s there.

How can I make it wrap if the text is too long, but at the same time include a few "what's up"'s if it has space?

[image: Image 1]

[play.tailwindcss.com](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ImFOHOTGbz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , you dont have to use flex with H1 tags , **H1** contain text and shouldnt 'semantically speaking' contain any divs .

Second **div's** are displayed as block by default thats why they take all the width and they wrap text of course .

Finally **H1** are blocks too but they are for text they should flex anything inside of them . in your example you havfe only one flex element under the **h1** tags wich is the div ! the `Whats ups` dont count as children nodes

[no flex working wrap words](https://play.tailwindcss.com/uuaajGTY7V)

Comment: Thank you!
I should have known this, but for some reason I just insisted on using flex..

I really appreciate the explanation!

Comment: you are very welcome, remember flex box is used for a flex-container , container type tag like divs, this is for semantic reasons , and should contain flex-items not just text .